# Why do I get accidental comments without (the required) email address?

Tags: comments, security

Somebody translated one of my tutorials [here](http://www.is-is.me/introducing-python-1-what-and-why/) (with my permission).

All fine but I got comments that seem unintended on two of my tutorials that the translation links to.

Now the weird thing is that they don't have an `comment_author_email`! I tried to post a comment on one of my tutorials (browser logged out) without specifying an email address and I couldn't (that's how it should be).

I am using the Anti-spam plugin which -so far- did an outstanding job for me.

Does anybody understand what's going on? Should I worry about my site being/getting hacked? What should I do?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: What's in the `comment_type` field?

Comment: @birgire: I see. It says `pingback`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Pingbacks/Trackbacks:

This is most likely a harmless case of *link notifications* to your blog (**A**) from the other blog (**B**), where:

- the `comment_author_email` field is usually empty,
- the `comment_type` field is either *pingback* or *trackback*,
- the `comment_author` field has the form:

  > The title of the post that contains a link to a post of blog **A** | The site name of blog **B**

It looks like the blog **B** has this activated:

> Attempt to notify any blogs linked to from the article

and blog **A** has this activated:

> Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)

in the *Discussion* settings.

Screenshot:

[image: settings]

[Here's](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Managing_Comments) a description of *trackbacks/pingbacks* from the Codex.

From the WordPress admin:

> Trackbacks are a way to notify legacy blog systems that you’ve linked
>   to them. If you link other WordPress sites they’ll be notified
>   automatically using pingbacks, no other action necessary.

[image: trackbacks]

The automatic pingbacks use the *XML-RPC* protocol to communicate, you can see it for example in the `comment_agent` field:

> The Incutio XML-RPC PHP Library -- WordPress/3.9.1